# How to assign multiple VLANS to a port?

Tags: vlan, gns3, private-vlan

I have  a simple question about a network (I am new to this concept so please correct me if I am wrong).

I have a simple network as shown (GNS3):

The network have 3VLANS (VLAN10 = DesignTeam, VLAN30 = EngTeam and VLAN20=Storage). What I would like is for Vlan30 to be accessed by VLAN10 & VLAN30.

I have done some research and I do few things here i.e use router on a stick method but I want to do this via multi-layer switch.

[image]

This is what I have done:
**First** created Vlans
**Second** assigned port to my VLAN's:
VLAN10 = f1/3
VLAN30 = f1/0
VLAN20 = f1/4
**Third** 
Assign ports to VLAN's:
`MainSwitch#conf t
     MainSwitch(config)#interface fastEthernet 1/4
     MainSwitch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 10
     MainSwitch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 30`

and then if I run show vlan-switch

I get different output each time (some port gets assigned to wrong VLAN's)

Am I doing anything wrong, anything I shod read further?

**EDIT:**
if I do: `show ip int br` i get:

```
Vlan10                     192.168.10.1    YES manual up                    up      
Vlan20                     192.168.20.1    YES manual up                    up      
Vlan30                     192.168.30.1    YES manual up                    up
```

I did `show lan-switch` and I get:

```
1    default                          active    Fa1/1, Fa1/2, Fa1/5, Fa1/6
                                            Fa1/7, Fa1/8, Fa1/9, Fa1/10

10   DesignTeam                       active    Fa1/3
20   Storage                          active    Fa1/4
30   EngTeam                          active    Fa1/0
```

If I access fa1/3 and do switch port access vlan10 then I get:

```
 1    default                          active    Fa1/1, Fa1/2, Fa1/5, Fa1/6
                                        Fa1/7, Fa1/8, Fa1/9, Fa1/10

10   DesignTeam                       active    Fa1/3 Fa1/4
20   Storage                          active    
30   EngTeam                          active    Fa1/0
```

As you can see the storage port moved to VLAN10 
This is what I want (VLAN 10 & 30 have access to 20):

```
 1    default                          active    Fa1/1, Fa1/2, Fa1/5, Fa1/6
                                        Fa1/7, Fa1/8, Fa1/9, Fa1/10

10   DesignTeam                       active    Fa1/3 Fa1/4
20   Storage                          active    Fa1/4
30   EngTeam                          active    Fa1/0 Fa1/4
```

Am I still doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're assigning ports the wrong way.  You have to specify each port before you enter the vlan command.  Something like this:

```
MainSwitch(config)#interface fastEthernet 1/4
MainSwitch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 20
MainSwitch(config)#interface fastEthernet 1/3
MainSwitch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 10
MainSwitch(config)#interface fastEthernet 1/0
MainSwitch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 30
```

Then you need to assign an IP address to each VLAN interface:

```
MainSwitch(config)#interface vlan 10
MainSwitch(config-if)#ip address 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.0
```

Etc.

Comment: Hi, So I have edited my question and as you can see the ports are assigned to VLAN and ip are also assigned to VLAN.

The question is: if I do go to fa1/3 and do switch port access lan 20 (I want f1/3 and f1/0 to access Storage). I see 1/4 move next VLAN10 (so now I don't have any port assign toVLAN20 which is storage)  

I'll appreciate if you can show me full configuration

Comment: do i have to make port f1/4 a trunk?

Comment: You want each port to be on one VLAN only. Your multilayer switch will route traffic between the VLANs.  Make sure your host devices have their default gateways set to the VLAN interface address.

Comment: Yes I would like each port to be in one VLAN - "Make sure your host devices have their default gateways set to the VLAN interface address"? in my case I did:
MainSwitch(config)# ip default-gateway 192.168.1.1? 
PC2 I am setting IP to:
ip 192.168.21.1/192.168.1.1 - but thats not working as i cannot ping from pc2 to pc1 (if VLAN can communicate then I should be able to ping it). Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: You don't need the "ip default gateway" statement on your switch--remove it.  Make sure all your hosts can ping their default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

It's feasible to  assign multiple VLANs  to one port on switch

This can be done by Configuring trunk port allowing all Vlans

`Switch(config)#int f0/1`

`Switch(config)#switchport mode trunk`

`Switch(config)#switchport trunk allowed Vlan all`

`Switch (config)#no shutdown`

**Or els we can assign specific multiple Vlan on single port** .

`Switch(config)#int f0/1`

`Switch(config)#Switchport mode trunk`

`Switch(config)#switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30

`Switch(config)#no shutdown`